# Как написать программу используя списки?

Tags: c, list

Помогите пожалуйста написать программу с комментариями, чтобы была возможность разобраться. Или скинуть сайт/книгу где доступным языком описано про списки. Так как 1 курс, нормально ничего не объясняют, информацию по спискам, которая изложена простым языком не нашел.
Вот само задание:

1. Найти первый элемент списка, который содержит положительное значение, вернуть адрес элемента.
2. Оставить в списке только последние вхождения одинаковых элементов, вернуть количество удаленных.

Comment: [Этого мало?](https://www.google.com/search?rls=org.mozilla%3Aru%3Aunofficial&ei=RNNPXpvsFcjmrgT1iZzYBg&q=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA+C&oq=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA+C&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.111588.113606..113902...0.2..0.110.634.1j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.YPrcqLpuFCM&ved=0ahUKEwibnrfL2OLnAhVIs4sKHfUEB2sQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

Answer (score 0):

Вот например есть такой букварь с примерами:

http://kspt.icc.spbstu.ru/media/files/course/algstr/algstr_2009.pdf

Третья глава (начало на 77 странице) - тема, которая Вас интересует.

Comment: Вряд ли это можно назвать букварем